# pass parameters into function php

Tags: javascript

i have a function call it: `myFunction(A,B,C)`
I have onchange event in my option select that process `"myFunction(A,B,C)"`

```
<select id='B' onchange="myFunction(userid,B,C)">
```

I have two radio buttons that also have an onclick event that process `"myFunction(A,B,C)"`

```
<input type=radio, id="Cyes" onclick="myFunction(userid,B,Cyes)">
<input type=radio, id="Cno" onclick="myFunction(userid,B,Cno)">
```

I am using ajax to process the event dynamically.

my question is, in the onclick event for the radio button, i do not want "myFunction" to process the parameter "B"

and in the onchange event for the options, i do not want "myFunction" to process the parameter "C"

i am using the same function but i only want the parameters to be processed for that particular onlick/onchange event. i want them to be ignore and i dont want any values pass to the db.

i am not sure if this is doable, but if it is, your input is much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: is myfunction a PHP function or a Javascript function?   Why not make it 2 functions, or add a 4th parameter to determine what needs processing?

Comment: err... is myFunction a javascript function or php function? edit: fosco you are fast... :-)

Comment: myfunction is a javascript/ajax script but it's within my php script; myfunction calls another php script after processing the paramenters.
<script>
myFunction(A,B,C)
{
var url="call my other php script"
}
</script>

<?php
onchange="myFunction(A,B,C)"
<?>

Comment: but it's not php...it's run on the client side, while PHP is run on the server.  Big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this by having arguments revert to default values if passing in null or undefined.

```
function myFunc (A, B, C) {
    A = A || "some default value";
    B = B || "some default value";
    C = C || "some default value";
}

// use A and B, not C:
myFunc('foo', 'bar');

// use A and C, not B:
myFunc('foo', null, 'something');
```

Alternatively you could pass in an object for the arguments and not worry about order:

```
function myFunc (argumentsObject) {
    var A = argumentsObject.a || "some default value";
    var B = argumentsObject.b || "some default value";
    var C = argumentsObject.c || "some default value";
}

// use A and B, not C:
myFunc({a: 'foo', b: 'bar'});

// use A and C, not B:
myFunc({a: 'foo', c: 'something'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define additional parameter identificated which event occurred? Or simply define two separate functions? Another way you can check in your code whenever or those parameters are set and decide accordingly, I think there something like `is_set(var_name)` in php.

EDIT.

According to you completion of question ywhy don't you simply do this?

```
function myFunc( A, B, C) {
    switch( C) {
        case "Cyes" : {
          //Do your job here
        }
        case "Cno"  : {
          //Do your job here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will see if is_set function can do what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm quite not sure whenever it will help you. Since while I was writing this you didn't put a clarification yet.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you are actually talking about a javascript function, not a PHP function.  Regardless, I would create 2 different functions.  Split any common functionality into a third function and call it from the other 2 functions.

Comment: i want the parameters i am calling in myFunction to be processed only based on the event called. so ignore the select id='' tag when i am doing an onclick event. and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly JS does not support default arguments (I did not know this), otherwise you could move B to be the last argument and call it like this;

> < onclick=MyFunction( A, C, B ) onchange=Myfunction( A, C ) >

But there is a way round it if you really must only have one function:

http://www.openjs.com/articles/optional_function_arguments.php